# What size should I make my online PDF brochure if I want I to fully span across the screen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like my brochure to appear like this, landscape to fit to screen so I am not sure what size to use.

http://www.93feeteast.co.uk/pdf/93_FEET_EAST_VENUE_BROCHURE.pdf

Comment: Hi, it depends on where you live and if you plan on printing the brochure. Generally a brochure is designed for a certain paper size. The paper size is really up to you. So this question is pretty broad. The PDF you linked is 11.693" W x 8.268" H. IDK why they made it that size...

Comment: @AndrewH It's A4, a European standard paper size (297x210mm)

Comment: Actually @AndrewLeach A4 is a ISO standard used in all countries except US and Canada

Answer (score 1):

You are free to make a PDF for digital display *any size* you wish. There is no "rule" or "standard" you must follow.

Something to consider though is usage. So you anticipate viewers wanting to print this PDF out? If so, then you'll want to keep standard, home-user, paper sizes in mind.

- You may wish to create the PDF so that each page fits nicely on a single sheet of paper for the user when printed.
- You can create a larger PDF and allow it to be scaled down when printed. This *could* possibly make some smaller type difficult to read.
- You can create a smaller PDF and allow it to take up less space on a printed page or to be scaled up when printed (often reducing quality)
- If you do *not* anticipate a user printing the PDF, then there are really no restrictions. Use whatever you feel looks nice on screen.

Most often in my experience, online display PDFs are created at standard paper sizes or very close to them, letter size for the US or whatever it is for UK (A4? A3?).

Comment: A4 (210mm x 297mm or 8.3" x 11.7") is the closest to US letter size. A4 is half the size of A3 (297mm x 420mm).

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr -- I've only ever done one UK piece, which was A4, but I had no idea if that was standard.

Comment: A4 is the ISO standard used in the UK, however photo prints are still commonly measured in inches.  And we still use miles and yards on road signs, and buy beer in pints, but milk and petroleum are sold in litres. It's totally mad!  I'm also old enough to remember imperial paper sizes such as foolscap folio and quarto which were still commonly used in the UK right up until the 1980s.

Answer (score 0):

I have done many of these and 90% of the times you do an A4 landscape (or Letter in the US), so that also works for print without forced stretching. Then, about 10% of the times you might be working in a Powerpoint format which is likely 1280x720 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for **"Should"** is nonexistent.

The answer for **"Can"** are many.

Normally a brochure is simply the same document intended for print, so you design for print and make a lower resolution to be posted online.

Letter? A4? Vertical?

---

But it would be interesting to know how many people actually print these days a PDF downloaded from the internet. I doubt they are so many.

For some years now, I only make PDF to be viewed on a computer, and since FullHD 16:9 is the most common format, I made them like that.

No left and right margins, no scrolling up and down fo read between columns on the same page, no extra resolution for print.

---

**AN IMPORTANT NOTE!**

I just noticed that you tagged your question Photoshop. DO NOT DO THAT.

Use Indesign, use Corel Draw, use Illustrator, or Affinity Publisher, Affinity Design, or Scribus that is free.

Use Word, use PowerPoint, or Libre Office...

**But do not use Photoshop.**

Comment: This is just a note:

My specific setup is a bit weird. I am so maniac of rounding numbers, and I work on the metric system.

Although I can simply set up my program in pixels, I still prefer to set it up in physical units. I feel uncomfortable making a tiny document of 16x9cm so I double it to 32x18cm. This way, the fonts can be used directly on the document without the need to be re-escalated or using tiny pt numbers.